# Auto update Docker Container by updated Github Repository

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, github, docker-swarm

I'm looking for an option to update my project that is supposed to run on a remote computer with my GitHub repo. I think about updating the container with a new image that I created on my local PC.

(I`ts a Python project)

thanks for the answer

I tried to update the project EXE file (and all of its dependencies as well), but I was just looking for a better and faster way

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: One way to achieve seamless integration between your pc and remote server is using ssh and docker contexts (https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/). That way you can even build the image on the remote server if that is your case/wish. In case you are using dockerhub as docker image repo (or check if it works for alternatives) there is project called Watchtower (https://github.com/containrrr/watchtower) - Watchtower will pull down your new image, gracefully shut down your existing container and restart it with the same options that were used when it was deployed initially